# Uniqueness of the Solution of a Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $f$ be a function, and some Cauchy problem

$$x'=f(t,x) \qquad x(t_0)=x_0 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The function $f$ can be autonomous or non-autonomous. Suppose that $f$ has some property that ensure the uniqueness of the solution. For example, $f$ is $C^1$ or Lipschitz continuous.

From the uniqueness of the solution, I know that if $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are solutions of \eqref{eq1}, then they must be equal. But I don't know what I can conclude in the following situations.

Suppose that I have two solutions to some Cauchy problem of $x'=f(t,x)$:

$$\psi:I_1\rightarrow\mathbb{E} \qquad \varphi:I_2\rightarrow\mathbb{E}$$
where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the maximum intervals where $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are defined.

**Situation 1:** Can exist $t_1 \in I_1$ and $t_2\in I_2$, such that $t_1,t_2 \notin I_1 \cap I_2$ and $\psi(t_1)=\varphi(t_2)$?

And if that is possible, what can be concluded from the relationship between $\psi$ and $\varphi$?

**Situation 2:** If exist $t_1,t_2\in I_1\cap I_2$ such that $\psi(t_1)=\varphi(t_2)$. It is possible to conclude that for all $t \in I_1\cap I_2,~\psi(t)=\varphi(t)$?

*I know this is true in the autonomous case, but what if it is non autonomous?*

**Situation 3:** It is possible to occur $I_1 \cap I_2=\{t_1\}$, such that $\psi(t_1)=\varphi(t_1)$?

Answer (score 2):

The point about autonomous solutions means this.  Suppose the first solution, say $x = u(t)$, and the second solution, $x=v(t)$, reach the same point $p$ at different times:
$u(t_1) = v(t_2) = p$.  Let $w(t) = u(t + t_1 - t_2)$.
Because the equation is autonomous, $x = w(t)$ is also
a solution.  Note that $w(t_2) = u(t_1) = p$. The two solutions $x = w(t)$ and $x = v(t)$ satisfy the same initial condition $x(t_2) = p$.  By the uniqueness property, these must be the same solution, i.e. $v(t) = w(t)$ for all $t$, i.e. $v(t) = u(t + t_1 - t_2)$.  This 
doesn't say that $x=u(t)$ and $x=v(t)$ are **the same**, rather they are related by a translation in time.

This works for an autonomous equation, but generally does not for non-autonomous, because translating a solution in time will generally not give you a solution.

Comment: I understood that, I edited the question to clarify my doubt. I posted the situations that are causing me confusion, could you help me?